# Is an hibernate "view" entity possible?

Tags: hibernate

Here's my problem:

I got 4 tables, T1, T2, T3 and T4 which have **in common** the following fields:

```
name surname address
```

Excluding for said fields those tables can have any number of other columns.
For example T1 could be like this:

```
name surname age address job
```

while T2 could be like this:

```
name surname address height
```

Now, I would like to create an entity which is not actually mapped 1:1 to any of those tables, but contains just common fields. For example:

```
 @Entity
 public class Person{ 
     @Column(name="name")
     private String name;
     @Column(name="surname")
     private String surname;
     @Column(name="address")
     private String address;


}
```

This entity will be used **just** in select statements and will have to return data from **ALL** the tables!

So, if T1 contains

```
Alex Cross 21 '3th streeth' employer
```

and T2 contains

```
Jhon Sullivan '4th streeth' 1.79
```

my select should return both of them. Supposing my entity is called "Person" it should return an array like this one:

```
Person1: {name: Alex, surname: Cross, address:'3th streeth'}
Person2: {name: Jhon, surname: Sullivan, address: '4th streeth'}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that by using just hybernate?

Comment: That looks like [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html) with TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy.

Comment: I am not so sure...when extending the parent class you will actually map the child class to a table.